# Need Help Checking if a file exists?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a way to Save files using a button that grabs the text in textboxes and saves them with a number specified in one of those text boxes. example: "enter employee id:"  (I would enter) "12345" and click the button, and it would save the file as 12345 with some info in it from other text boxes.

Now I also have implemented a way to check if that file exists in two separate folders so that is doesn't create a file with multiple of the same name.

Now I am trying to check if the file exists (in both directories) again when someone clicks a button to login on a separate page but I run into a problem where it always tells me the file doesn't exist. I'm new to programming so I'm a little lost. Here is my code:

***Login Page:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Rent_a_Car
{
    public partial class Employee_Login_Page : Form
    {
        public Employee_Login_Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string ManagerPath = @"C:\Users\mogee\Visual Studios Project Custom Files\Rent A Car Employee Id's\Managers\Manager_Ids.txt"; //Path To Manager Logins
        string EmployeePath = @"C:\Users\mogee\Visual Studios Project Custom Files\Rent A Car Employee Id's\Staff\Staff_Ids.txt"; //Path to Employees Logins

        string FileName; //Declares FileName
        bool FileExists;

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Employee_Id_TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&           //Checks Characters entered are Numbers Only and allows them
                (e.KeyChar != '0'))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)                                         //Checks if The "Enter" Key is pressed
            {
                Login_Btn_Click(this, new EventArgs());                             //If so activate the Login Button
            }
        }

        private void Employee_Login_Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Login_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FileName = Employee_Id_TextBox.Text=".txt"; //sets the string FileName to Employee Id Entered
            string pathManagerString = System.IO.Path.Combine(ManagerPath, FileName); //Combine Manager Path With New Id and sets to pathManagerString
            string pathEmployeeString = System.IO.Path.Combine(EmployeePath, FileName); //Combine Manager Path With New Id and sets to pathEmployeeString

            if (FileExists = File.Exists(pathEmployeeString)) //Check If Employee ID File Exists in Employee folder
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Employee ID Entered as Employee");
                EmployeeHome_Page myForm = new EmployeeHome_Page();
                this.Hide();
                myForm.ShowDialog();
            }
            else if(FileExists = File.Exists(pathManagerString))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Employee ID Entered as Manager");
                EmployeeHome_Page myForm = new EmployeeHome_Page();
                this.Hide();
                myForm.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Employee ID Not Found");
            }
            //need to check logins and wether they are manager or just standard users/and if so activate manager button
        }
    }
}
```

***Second Form:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Rent_a_Car
{
    public partial class AddEmployee_Page : Form
    {
        public AddEmployee_Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string ManagerPath = @"C:\Users\mogee\Visual Studios Project Custom Files\Rent A Car Employee Id's\Managers";
        string EmployeePath = @"C:\Users\mogee\Visual Studios Project Custom Files\Rent A Car Employee Id's\Staff";
        private void AddEmployee_Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        string FileName; //Declares FileName
        bool FileExists;

        private void CancelAddEmployee_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EmployeeHome_Page myForm = new EmployeeHome_Page ();
            this.Hide();
            myForm.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void AddEmployee_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileName = EmployeeID_AddEmployee_TextBox.Text; //sets the string FileName to Employee Id Entered
            string pathManagerString = System.IO.Path.Combine(ManagerPath, FileName); //Combine Manager Path With New Id and sets to pathManagerString
            string pathEmployeeString = System.IO.Path.Combine(EmployeePath, FileName); //Combine Manager Path With New Id and sets to pathEmployeeString

            if (FirstName_AddEmployee_TextBox.Text == "" || LastName_AddEmployee_TextBox.Text == "" || EmployeeID_AddEmployee_TextBox.Text == "")  //checks if any feild are empty if so show prompt
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Missing Information!");
            }
            else if (EmployeeID_AddEmployee_TextBox.TextLength < 5)      //checks if employee id is less then 5 digits long, if so display message
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ID Needs To Be Five Numbers Long");
            }
            else if (IsManager_CheckBox.Checked)  //checks if manager
            {
                if (FileExists = File.Exists(pathManagerString)) //Check If Employee ID File Exists in manager folder
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Employee ID Exists Please Choose Another Id #");
                }
                else if (FileExists = File.Exists(pathEmployeeString)) //Check If Employee ID File Exists in employee folder
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Employee ID Exists Please Choose Another Id #");
                }
                else
                {
                    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
                        new System.IO.StreamWriter(pathManagerString, true))
                    {
                        file.WriteLine("Manager First Name: " + FirstName_AddEmployee_TextBox.Text); //Writes First Name
                        file.WriteLine("Manager Last Name: " + LastName_AddEmployee_TextBox.Text);//Writes Last Name
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (FileExists = File.Exists(pathEmployeeString)) //Check If Employee ID File Exists in emoployee folder
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Employee ID Exists Please Choose Another Id #");
                }
                else if(FileExists = File.Exists(pathManagerString)) //Check If Employee ID File Exists in manager folder
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Employee ID Exists Please Choose Another Id #");
                }
                else
                {
                    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
                        new System.IO.StreamWriter(pathEmployeeString, true))
                    {
                        file.WriteLine("Employee First Name: " + FirstName_AddEmployee_TextBox.Text); //Writes First Name
                        file.WriteLine("Employee Last Name: " + LastName_AddEmployee_TextBox.Text);//Writes Last Name
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void FirstName_AddEmployee_TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void EmployeeID_AddEmployee_TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&           //Checks Characters entered are Numbers Only and allows them
    (e.KeyChar != '0'))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void IsManager_CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At `FileName = Employee_Id_TextBox.Text=".txt";`, I think you meant to do `+ ".txt"` not `=`.

Comment: I just saw your message as well as Always_a_Learner's Message about that It didn't seem to work, in my response to that answer i also tried FileName = Employee_Id_TextBox.Text; and that didn't seem to work either, any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line of code of Login_Btn_Click method:

Old

```
FileName = Employee_Id_TextBox.Text=".txt";
```

Replacement

```
 FileName = Employee_Id_TextBox.Text+".txt";
```

And update location of both folder:

```
string ManagerPath = @"C:\Users\mogee\Visual Studios Project Custom Files\Rent A Car Employee Id's\Managers";
string EmployeePath = @"C:\Users\mogee\Visual Studios Project Custom Files\Rent A Car Employee Id's\Staff";
```

Comment: So I tried That and It Unfortunatly did't change anything and still tells me that my message that the "Employee Id Was Not Found", I also tried:                                               
          FileName = Employee_Id_TextBox.Text; With no luck Any Ideas?

Comment: i doubt both location, double check location is same or not in configuration file and in executables?

Comment: Here is difference C:\Users\mogee\Visual Studios Project Custom Files\Rent A Car Employee Id's\Managers\Manager_Ids.txt and C:\Users\mogee\Visual Studios Project Custom Files\Rent A Car Employee Id's\Managers

Comment: string ManagerPath = @"C:\Users\mogee\Visual Studios Project Custom Files\Rent A Car Employee Id's\Managers";
        string EmployeePath = @"C:\Users\mogee\Visual Studios Project Custom Files\Rent A Car Employee Id's\Staff"; update this as it in login form

Comment: Gotcha Gotcha, I think I just Had a type when I tried it the first time, Thank you So much!